# Contact us: unable to resize the message area, why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Why the message area in the Contact Us page (https://stackoverflow.com/contact) is small and set to `resize:none`? Writing a long message is a bit difficult in such situation.

[image]

I don't know if it was always like that but I use it before and didn't feel that it's was very small and we cannot resize to see the full message.

Can we at least enable the resize so it's easier to write long messages?

Comment: [Friedhelm Hillebrand had the task of setting the limit on the amount of characters a text message could contain](https://thehub.smsglobal.com/why-is-an-sms-160-characters): his work lead to a choice of 160 chars for SMS, later refined to 140 chars for Twitter. That [ought to be enough for anybody](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bill_Gates). (joke aside, yes, box is too small)

Comment: Did you not try reporting this to support? :P

Comment: @James haha, I tried but I got mad writing there :p

Comment: Yup, I have noticed this too. I have found using `size: 10em` in the style editor works pretty well. YMMV.

Comment: @TravisJ this is getting many upvotes, but am wondering why there is still no answer/comment from support guys or a moderator? is this normal? should I simply wait?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Oh man. Sorry, I thought you knew. This is just community support. Even if there was moderator support (which there probably is) that still isn't going to change the developer timeline for fixing stuff like this. Often, super simple things are easily fixed, hopefully this is one of them. However, don't be surprised if this takes 6-8 months to see progress.

Comment: @TravisJ well I wasn't hoping to have this fixed within 1 or 2 days :) I know that it need to enter a complex process but I was wondering to get a reply like "Ok, we will see this .." or "you are right, we will forward this to support" or "we are aware about this, and it will be fixed in the next update", etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Ah, sorry I misunderstood what you were asking me a little bit. Usually you will see them add a tag of [status-] to the post for stuff like this if it has been seen by someone who can take action on it. Depending on the status suffix, you will know what the planned course of action is. It can take a while for them to place the tag on these, but I wouldn't expect it to take very long; maybe a few weeks at most, for critical stuff it can be same day. They follow the bug tag fairly closely.

Comment: @TravisJ ok thanks for the clarification ;)

Comment: It's always been fixed size, but that fixed size used to be 7 lines high - now it's not. Looks like a casualty of the responsive redesign - we'll look into it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's back to 7 lines - with a bonus resizing ability<sup>*</sup>!

[image: screenshot of now not awful textarea]

Thanks for the report and patience!

<sup>*resizing ability available only in browsers that support resizing textareas and possibly Quebec.</sup>

Comment: great thank you ;) let's send a bunch of message to test :p

Comment: What's so special about Quebec?

Comment: @Shog9, you marked this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371260/comment-icons-always-visible-a-new-feature-or-a-bug *status-bydesign* so I understand it won't change right? what should I do if I want changes to be done? can I edit it to make it a feature request and remove your tag?

Comment: By-design means the change is intentional - it looks how it is intended to look. That *definitely* doesn't mean it will or should continue to always look that way, @temani; our fearless designers are working hard on less... awkward... appearances that'll hopefully achieve the same ends. If you have ideas for improvements, consider posting a new question that lays them out along with your reasoning (tag it [meta-tag:feature-request]). Oh, btw: if I edit a post, you can ping me in comments on *that post* - just prefix my name with @.