# Comment icons always visible, a new feature or a bug?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, design, comments

I recently noticed that the icons used to upvote or flag comments are visible by default.

[image]

Is this a new feature or a bug?

By the way, if it's a new feature, I don't like it. It seems to be a lot of visual repetition especially when we have many upvotes.

[image]

Comment: I'm so glad I'm not going crazy, I was just looking at a question and thought "Wow the flag icon seems to be jumping off the page at me, has it always been like this or did they just change it?"

Comment: @DavyM yes they changed, it also made me crazy :p

Comment: To make the flag option more noticable I guess.

Comment: Is this to help increase flags for "unwelcoming" content?

Comment: It is still not visible, they should perhaps try making it blink, and add some rainbow colors...

Comment: @BhargavRao by the way, they forget to make the "cross icon" for the deletion visible .. Hope they don't add it too ...

Comment: Someone's asked the same question on MSE [Why are the comment upvote and flag options always appearing now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312794/why-are-the-comment-upvote-and-flag-options-always-appearing-now)... Though it's attracted some downvotes lol, I guess here we think that it's a much more useful topic than they do there.

Comment: @Dukeling true, wanted to first be sure it's not a bug and see if a lot of people agree with this ... but it seems that many don't like it

Comment: many people don't like change period, good or bad

Comment: I upvoted your question because I was curious about the same thing, but I don't dislike the change. For the most part I don't really notice it, but I like that it's more evident when you've already flagged a comment.

Comment: @DavyM I'm guessing that users thought that the question isn't good enough that the author should earn rep from it, while here on MSO there's no rep to be earned. (I'm the one who posted the MSE question.)

Comment: I consider it a feature for using StackOverflow on a touchscreen. But I agree that it jumps into the eye.

Comment: This isn't very welcoming.. All those flags make me feel like I'm walking around a minefield now.

Comment: I didn't even notice until I read this post.

Comment: @Floern Minefield, indeed. It reminds me of a minesweeper now. It's, as if like, if you think (or know for sure) that a comment can cause an explosion - you ⚑ it.

Comment: Adding the following CSS will restore the original functionality (corrected): `.comment:not(:hover) .comment-up-off, .comment:not(:hover) .comment-flag:not(.flag-on) { visibility: hidden; }`

Comment: Maybe if the gray were lighter and/or icons smaller it would be better, but right now it's very distracting.

Comment: It also makes it *really* difficult for me to figure out what upvote count now belongs to which comment. This is so noisy and terrible on my eyes. Makes me want to avoid comments altogether, but maybe that’s the intention after all.

Comment: Like the rest of the latest redesign this is a step backwards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My bad, we should have posted something on this when we rolled it out.

As mentioned by Monica, this is an intentional change to make flagging more discoverable. We can all agree it definitely does that.

This is a work in progress and we are working on some additional changes to improve the layout of comments. These changes will build on the changes we made to make comments responsive and will use our [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/guidelines/using-stacks) design library. As you can imagine and as this post proves, changes to comments layout can be controversial, so I'll post more as we rollout additional changes.

Comment: Maybe you could hide them again by default after someone reaches a certain amount of comment flags network-wide?

Comment: should I open a new feature request for this in order to make some changes? or should I wait for the futures changes?

Comment: Upvoted for visibility, not because I agree with the change.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hold off for now.

Comment: This UI change adds a lot of clutter to the comments. I also don't understand what was wrong with it in the first place. It's pretty intuitive to think that if someone is bothered by a comment, they'll probably naturally hover over it and be able to flag from there. Same with upvote.

Comment: I suggest auto-flagging every comment made on posts by new users, with the option of cancel them afterwards. That's the only way to be sure that new users are fully supported in their endeavours here.

Comment: Why is it that design changes like this (and there are many others recently) aren’t actually announced by the team but have to be accidentally found by community members? Not only does that make it really hard to actually discover reasonings behind the changes, but this is also a terrible way to collect feedback. So you should *really* consider announcing these properly in a post, so people can directly send back feedback about it.

Answer (score 52):

While we are discussing this change, this feature could be better applied only to lower-rep users instead of everyone (but this should probably be a feature-request).

In the meantime, I have created a temporary fix for those who are already familiar with the comment action icons and wish for them to remain hidden until the comment is hovered upon:

**[Userscript Source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js)** ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ReduceClutter.user.js))

[image]

Comment: Any way you could have it collapse the comment back down so one line comments don't take up 2 lines?

Comment: The question is now tagged with *status-bydesign*, should I then consider making it a feature request if I want them to remove the icons? or should I wait?

Comment: @NathanOliver I think there is no reasonable way of making the comments single-line, short of moving the flag icon to the right of the upvote button, therefore increasing the left margin a considerable bit for all comments. Originally comments was already displayed this way, taking up a minimum of two lines, screenshot here https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/#comment-user-colors

Comment: Please! My eyes are bleeding. @TemaniAfif

Comment: Whew! Thank you! I was about to get really really annoyed, it clutters things up awful bad.

Comment: How about making the feature toggle-able? Showing all by default so that new users see it, and possible to turn off. I think I would keep it on because then I can upvote comments using vimium.

Answer (score 29):

**Problem:**

[image]

From a UX perspective this indeed feels like UI clutter.

It's akin to opening a web form and all of the required fields are immediately outlined with a thick red border in an effort to let me know which fields are required.

It feels like I am expected to immediately perform an action on every single comment.

---

**Suggestion:**

If keeping it visible is for the sake of discoverability then may I suggest:

[image]

for the sake of UI consistency between posts and comments.

As a bonus (not shown in my the screenshot because I was lazy) this would save vertical height for single-line comments.

Comment: I don't like the idea of flag icons on the right, and I also don't understand your Update.

Comment: @pnuts It was meant to serve as an ode to my "..immediately outlined with a thick red border..." statement but that obviously wasn't clear so I'll forgo it.

Comment: @TylerH See my recent comment. Thanks

Comment: @pnuts I assume that is in reference to the comment I deleted since I saw that  you deleted yours, lol.

Answer (score 19):

Reposting [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312794/why-are-the-comment-upvote-and-flag-options-always-appearing-now/312796#312796) from MSE by Monica Cellio over to here. Seems to be part of the July update and is geared towards making the UI to flag more discoverable.

---

From the [team DAG announcement for July](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312041/162102):

> Comment flagging improvements: To align with the new CoC we will be making various changes in how comment flagging works.
>
> - Allowing new users to flag comments on their post
> - Updating flagging options to match CoC
> - Updating commenting UI to make flagging more discoverable
> - Provide better feedback on flag submission

Comment: Then why not make the flag twice as large as the upvote arrow.

Comment: @usr2564301 ask the design team

Comment: @usr2564301 the flag clickable area is already like twice as large as the upvote clickable area.

Comment: @TylerH: a-ha. The arrow is (on my Mac) 16x8 and the flag is 12x14. Seems someone indeed anticipated *flagging* being more popular than *upvoting*, on any random comment. Shall I now dare measuring the sizes of the upvote versus the downvote arrow? (As downvoting is perceived more unwelcoming to new users than upvoting, so any chance of accidentally clicking the wrong button must be minimized.)

Answer (score 13):

Since this is now `status-bydesign` and the reason is discoverability, I would suggest, to make it possible, to opt-out of it.

If someone is changing the settings, I am sure that person already discovered that feature.