# New comment's red flag shows text 'flag' instead of icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, comment-flags

I loved the new red flag shown near to the flagged comment, but it shows a red **"flag"** text immediately after the flag action, like :

[image]

After a refresh, the red icon appears and it looks perfect :

[image]

I think it should show the red flag symbol instead, directly after the action.

Comment: Also reported on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312797/flagging-a-comment-displays-the-word-flag-changes-to-image-of-red-flag-upon-r

Comment: Yeek! Flags are [everywhere](https://i.imgur.com/YqBm7b4.png)!

Comment: @Victoria https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371260/comment-icons-always-visible-a-new-feature-or-a-bug

Comment: @Nilesh, thank you! I was hoping somebody already reported this.

Comment: In line with the welcoming initiative the devs are trying to make as many visual cues as possible in order to facilitate flagging by new users. Part of this is why comment icons have become huge and always visible. Unfortunately there's no culturally unambiguous way in which to draw a flag, so for the sake of inclusiveness the word "flag" is spelled out so that new users pressing buttons can be sure what they did was in fact _flag_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the StackOverflow moderator **[Aaron Shekey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2804712/aaron-shekey)** says in **[This POST](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312882/299570)**, the bug is fixed now and will go out during the next build.