# The edited icon is too prominent

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design, comments

I just noticed that the icon for the edited comments has changed recently:

[image: Edit Icon]

Is there any reason to make such a minor thing so prominent?

I am requesting that it be made the same color as the timestamp text.

---

Also, I just noticed there is some inconsistency in colors here (the timestamp text):

[image: inconsistency]

That should imho be eliminated too.

Comment: Just in case you want to see it in action.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - that is prominent. Looks like a "click to edit" button.

Comment: It had to be "fixed" earlier, as it was made very less prominent, read completely gone. I guess it needs to find its middle ground between that and its current prominence ...

Comment: Those who have previously installed the ReduceClutter userscript now has this [implemented](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js#L55).

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the "upvote triangle" and "flag sign" on the comments are bigger than before, too?

Comment: "Is there any reason to make such a minor thing so prominent?" I suppose it's useful in cases where someone modifies comment to make a reply look stupid.

Comment: That doesn't even look like a crayon. Seems to be a falling exclamation mark. is this intended to have several shades, depending on how many times the comment was edited?

Comment: Not only that, they used to be hidden, when not hovered. [See this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371260/comment-icons-always-visible-a-new-feature-or-a-bug) @zx8754

Comment: How is the icon different from how it used to look? Wasn't it just missing for a few hours? *I just noticed there is some inconsistency in colors here* - I can't see a difference here either. The alt text doesn't explain it either.

Comment: @pnuts To be fair, I'm guessing. But, as it's a recent change, it strikes me as an oversight. I could be dead wrong. The [design] tag is the important one here.

Comment: @pnuts I can't follow you. What of my question does indicate I need support? In best case "discussion".

Comment: @BSMP take a closer look, the color is different. I Can't agree the edited Icon looks the same as previously.

Comment: @pnuts I tried using the eyedropper in Photoshop and ColorZilla and still didn't see a color difference if I picked from the same spot. I also see a shade difference in the time in the image but not anywhere on the page.

Comment: Would it be better to have it look like this? - Jacob H 5 mins ago (edited twice)

Comment: Also, the two icons are not different colors. I'm guessing your eyes play tricks on you because of the other text colors near the icon in the second example whereas in the first one there is only a gray line.

Comment: Oh the TEXT not the icons. Yeah that is a different shade. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question to make it more clear @JacobH

Comment: It's also quite confusing as the pencil is very commonly used as a "button" for "edit this".  Why not just put " (edited)" after the date?

Comment: They've edited the color of the edited icon, now it's too subdued and very easy to miss. I kind of liked the dark one better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added a tiny bit of opacity to this icon. We've switched from static pngs to SVG that inherits the text color. This is important for theming flexibility. It's now a bit more subtle by default ✌️.

Comment: It looks oddly misaligned. Top is fine, bottom...

Answer (score 7):

> Also, I just noticed there is some inconsistency in colors here (the timestamp text):

The color difference is due to having visited the link. Normal link color:

```
.comment-date, .comment-date>a, .comment-date>a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #9199a1;
}
```

Visited link color:

```
.post-text a:visited, .comment-text a:not(.comment-user):visited {
    color: #535a60;
}
```

You can make it happen on purpose by clicking the timestamp.