# Comment upvote buttons look 'used' when reviewing on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, mobile-web, comment-votes

When I'm reviewing on Meta Stack Overflow on an iPhone with Safari on iOS (11.4.1), the comment upvote buttons are *red*.

[image]

This is rather annoying, as it makes me think I've upvoted them, which is only the case for the one with the *black* upvote button (and the 1 in front).

It's also happening on the main site, but there the buttons are blue:

[image]

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg9m0.png) is how the Meta Stack Exchange review queue looks on mobile; all comment vote buttons are gray, consistent with the look outside the review queue. So it seems to be a (Meta) Stack Overflow-only problem.

The problem does not occur when reviewing in 'desktop mode': [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiNbm.png). I'm pretty sure it was introduced with [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371260/4751173).

Comment: Chrome on Android *almost* shows the same behavior. The comment vote buttons are grey initially, but if you upvote, then retract your upvote, the 'active' styling is retained (though the little number indicating the number of upvotes is properly updated). It is extremely confusing, though -- agreed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this back in August along with [this other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279328/delete-comment-on-mobile-version-shows-weird-looking-combination-of-icon-and-let/314593#314593). The original cause was related: special-casing the mobile theme when rendering comments, even if there was no mobile theme for the current page - but this ended up being an easy to side-step, since prior to the fix we'd already altered the display of the vote/flag buttons to be always-visible on the full theme as well, so there was no longer any need to special-case mobile in that regard *even if* the current page was a mobile-themed page.

tl;dr: you shouldn't have seen this behavior in the past 5 months; please let me know if I'm wrong.